# How to use SQL Distinct Properly?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table like this:

**table supervisor**

[image]

I want the result like this:

[image]

and like this

[image]

I use this query, but this doesn't work out

```
Select Lecturer1,
Count(Student)
From supervisor
```

I use this also

```
Select Distinct Lecturer1,
(Select Count(Student) From Supervisor)
From Supervisor
Order By Supervisor.Lecuter1
```

still doesn't work out.

Comment: should be using group by not distinct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using an aggregate property such as Count(), Min(), Max(), Sum() etc.. You will have to 'Group By' any other column you are trying to query.

Such as

```
  Select Lecturer1,Count(Student)
    From supervisor
  Group by Lecturer1
```

Distinct will give you the distinct from each column selected in totality.